# function parameter type checking in ANSI-C with empty parameter list

Tags: c, ansi-c

In K&R it says that declaring a function prototype such as `void foo();` with an empty parameter list turns off function parameter type checking.  Is this only for `foo` or for all functions?

Comment: In modern C you would typically use the keyword `void` to indicate that a function doesn't take any arguments. Declaring functions without a parameter list went out of fashion some 30 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only applies to the function in question, not globally.

Comment: Could you reference something such as from the c89 standard which makes it clear?

Comment: @Robert: Sorry, i don't have it here. If you have it you should look for a heading like "Function declarators", at least that's how it's called in C99. You will find that it only talks about that specific function or it's declaration.

Comment: That's K&R Second Edition, I assume. In the first edition, function declarations always had empty parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It turns off the checking only for functions that are declared with empty parameter list, all other functions will still be checked.

Comment: Could you reference something such as from the c89 standard which makes it clear?